# Redshift UDF: Unmarshall DynamoDB JSON to regular JSON

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-redshift, user-defined-functions

I have a JSON value stored with DynamoDB markers in a Redshift table. I would like to keep it as json column without exploding. The issue I have is that the json is with dynamodb markers as shown in the example below. I’m looking to remove dynamodb markers so that I can store regular json and parse it later. Can someone guide me on how to achieve this using UDF in Redshift?

Example:

**INPUT**

```
{
    "assignees": {
        "L": [{
            "M": {
                "departmentName": {
                    "S": "XYZ"
                },
                "lastName": {
                    "S": "ABC"
                },
                "displayName": {
                    "S": "ABC,XYZ"
                },
                "departmentId": {
                    "S": 123
                },
                "active": {
                    "N": 1
                },
                "employeeId": {
                    "S": 456
                },
                "title": {
                    "S": "TEST"
                },
                "jobLevel": {
                    "N": 6
                },
                "firstName": {
                    "S": "ABC"
                },
                "alias": {
                    "S": "XYZ"
                },
                "userType": {
                    "S": "TEST_USER"
                },
                "email": {
                    "S": "email@domain.com"
                },
                "groupName": null
            }
        }]
    }
}
```

**DESIRED OUTPUT**

```
{
    "assignees": [{
        "departmentName": "XYZ",
        "lastName": "ABC",
        "displayName": "ABC,XYZ"
        "departmentId": 123
        "active":1
        "employeeId": 456
        "title": "TEST"
        "jobLevel": 100
        "firstName": "ABC"
        "alias": "XYZ"
        "userType": "TEST_USER"
        "email": "email@domain.com"
        "groupName": null
    }]
}
```

Need assistance with writing python UDF.